# Perl grouping data in columns according to the SubjectID

Tags: perl

I want to group some data based on the `SubjectID` column

Here is my data

```
SubjectID      Result1          Result2 
1                1.2              3.5
1                1.4              3.4
2                2.3              0.23
3                3.4               2.3
3                4.5               3.4
3                2.3               3.2
```

I want to group the results according to the `SubjectID` and get the minimum and maximum values.

This is what the result should look like:

```
SubjectID     Result1Min      Result1Max        Result2Min        Result2Max
1                 1.2            1.4                3.4              3.5
2                 2.3            2.3                0.23             0.23
3                 2.3            4.5                2.3              3.4
```

I tried doing this by trying to make two hashes of arrays so the `SubjectID` would be the key and the results would be the value. But I can't figure out how to group the results according to `SubjectID`.

Comment: Your data looks like it has come from a database. If so, then it would be best to get the database engine to do the calculations for you. Where does your program get its data?

Answer (score 1):

This gives the expected output:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

<>; # Skip the header.
my %h;
while (<>) {
    my ($id, $r1, $r2) = split;
    my $is_new = ! exists $h{$id};
    $h{$id}{r1}{max} = $r1 if $is_new || $r1 > $h{$id}{r1}{max};
    $h{$id}{r1}{min} = $r1 if $is_new || $r1 < $h{$id}{r1}{min};
    $h{$id}{r2}{max} = $r2 if $is_new || $r2 > $h{$id}{r2}{max};
    $h{$id}{r2}{min} = $r2 if $is_new || $r2 < $h{$id}{r2}{min};
}

for my $id (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %h) {
    say join "\t", $id, map @{ $h{$id}{$_} }{qw{ min max }}, qw( r1 r2 );
}
```

It uses just one hash table, the SubjectID being the topmost key. The inner hashes have the `r1`/`r2` as keys, and the innermost hashes have `max` and `min` as keys. The `$is_new` boolean variable is used to initialize the results for a not yet processed id.

Comment: That's very *choroba*!

Answer (score 0):

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/aAZu18TE)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(min max);

# Set Data
my $data = {
   1 => {
      Result1 => { data=> [1.2, 1.4] },
      Result2 => { data=> [3.5, 3.4] }
   },
   2 => {
      Result1 => { data => [2.3] },
      Result2 => { data => [.23] }
   },
   3 => {
      Result1 => { data => [3.4, 4.5, 2.3] },
      Result2 => { data => [2.3, 3.4, 3.2] }
   }
};

# Find Min/Max
foreach my $subjectId (sort keys %$data ){
   foreach my $result ( sort keys %{$data->{$subjectId}} ){
      my $obj = $data->{$subjectId}{$result};
      $obj->{min} = min @{$obj->{data}};
      $obj->{max} = max @{$obj->{data}};
   }
}

# Output
print qq{SubjectID\tResult1Min\tResult1Max\tResult2Min\tResult2Max\n};
foreach my $subjectId (sort keys %$data ){
   print qq{$subjectId\t\t};
   foreach my $result ( sort keys %{$data->{$subjectId}} ){
      my $obj = $data->{$subjectId}{$result};
      print qq{$obj->{min}\t\t$obj->{max}\t\t};
   }
   print qq{\n};
}
```

The finding of min/max and output could be combined for shorter code, but this should be enough to demonstrate.